# UnsatisfiedLinkError caused by org.gdal.ogr.ogrJNI.GetDriverCount()

Tags: java, windows, gdal, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am developing in Java on Windows 7 with Eclipse (Luna).

I am using gdal for some ogr processes and running the application from eclipse is fine, but running from command line on the same machine is running into problems.

and I get the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.ogr.ogrJNI.GetDriverCount()I
    at org.gdal.ogr.ogrJNI.GetDriverCount(Native Method)
    at org.gdal.ogr.ogr.GetDriverCount(ogr.java:170)
```

I've added all of the directories under gdal that contain dlls and jars to both the `CLASSPATH` and `PATH` environmental.

I thought it might be the libraries, but I am using the deployment location in the paths, which works in eclipse.

In the eclipse project's `.classpath` file I noticed that the gdal reference has an attribute called CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY, this links to the gdal\dll directory, but I have already included that in the paths:

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="dependencies/gdal/bin/gdal/java/gdal.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY" value="dependencies/gdal/dll"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

This is the only difference I can see. How do you replicate this on a windows machine or is that handled by the CLASSPATH and PATH?

Do I need to reference the individual dlls? I have tried the 4 that normally go with gdal.jar, but that doesnt change the error that I am getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this article / Post:
http://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorial/installing-gdal-for-windows

It talks about setting up GDAL for windows and is a lot more straight forward than the spiders web of includes and references I had.

I took all the references to gdal off the ClassPath and Path.

I then added only the link to the `gdal/bin/gdal/java/gdal.jar` on the ClassPath and a link to `gdal/dll` directory on the Path. That is it... that is all you need to do...

There are mentions in the post about `GDAL_DATA` and `GDAL_DRIVERS`, I didnt need those, but you could add those to be safe.

**update**
`GDAL_DATA`  is needed, just reference `gdal/bin/gdal_data` iirc

I can only deduce that Eclipse doesnt use the classpath so the extra references I put on the ClassPath were just confusing matters.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded binaries from

> https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries

Since the binaries were **build** with **MSVC 2017 x64** I had to install the

> Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributeable

On my Windows machine to solve `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

My older `Gdal Version 2.4.0` worked with already existing `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributeable`