# Error when opening file gdal java

Tags: java, gdal, geotiff

I am trying to load geotiff file with gdal api (java). Here is my test code.

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        gdal.AllRegister();
        Dataset dataset = gdal.Open("output.tif");
    }
}
```

But i have an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.Dataset_SWIGUpcast(J)J
at org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.Dataset_SWIGUpcast(Native Method)
at org.gdal.gdal.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.java:20)
at org.gdal.gdal.gdal.Open(gdal.java:585)
at org.gdaltest.projection.App.main(App.java:18)
```

I am using maven project, so i added gdal dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gdal</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdal</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using windows 10 and installed gdal 2.1.0. I had already set environment variable GDAL_DATA and Gdal directory in path.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The dreaded UnsatisfiedLinkErrors are quite common problems when having to deal with native libraries.

Normally you need to set the java.library.path VM parameter so that Java can find the native libs.

[See an example here](http://gdal-dev.osgeo.narkive.com/MJ8G6XNw/native-library-load-failed-while-using-gdal-maven-dependency-unsatisfiedlinkerror)

[Another gdal related unsatisfied link error issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573954/unsatisfiedlinkerror-caused-by-org-gdal-ogr-ogrjni-getdrivercount)

Comment: I have no proble executing

Comment: i have no problem executiong ogr.RegisterAll(), gdal.AllRegister(), gdal.VersionInfo(). But i still have the same error when i use method gdal.open("<PATH_TIFF_FILE>")

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the problem.

I replaced the jar file located in repository maven (*C:\Users\Myuser.m2\repository\org\gdal\gdal\2.1.0*) by the jar file located in the gdal folder (*C:\Program Files\GDAL\java*): and now it works.

Comment: i mean jar file in C:\Program Files\GDAL\java